# How can I remove every occurence of "<p>&nbsp;</p>" from the data in a column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I have this table with data that I need to clean up.

I am trying to convert this to XML but first I need to remove every occurence of `<p>&nbsp;</p>` **that appears inside text** inside the `Text` column:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Detail] (
    [DetailId]       INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Text]            NVARCHAR (4000) NULL,
    [Detail]          NVARCHAR (4000) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Detail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DetailId] ASC)
);
```

Can anyone suggest how I could do this? Please note that I am not at this time wanting to convert anything to XML. I would just like to remove this text string or would it be more appropriate to say replace it with "".

Thanks

Comment: With an UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the following if you wanted to clean it from all rows in the table:

```
update  dbo.Detail
set     Text = REPLACE(Text, '<p>&nbsp;</p>', '');
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I will wait a while to see if anyone has any comments on this and then accept if everyone seems to agree it's the way to go.

Comment: Instead of seeing what the masses to you should test this and see if it does what you want it to. It should do exactly what you stated you want done.

Comment: @SamanthaJ et al, there should be a WHERE clause so it doesn't waste resources locking and updating rows that don't have that text pattern in it: `WHERE [Text] LIKE N'%<p>&nbsp;</p>%'`.

Comment: @srutzky, Wouldn't adding a WHERE clause that filters the data with a LIKE waste more resources in some scenarios?  For instance, if every record had '<p>&nbsp;</p>' SQL Server would first have to check if the value existed in the field, and the find it again to replace every instance of it.

Comment: @SamanthaJ and animateme, I did some testing via SQL Profiler and it looks like I was wrong. It does appear to do more locking/unlocking when specifying a WHERE clause. I will keep my comment posted so that anyone else who might have this concern can see that it has been dealt with. +1